# Global xaml resources only defined once in a class libray project

Tags: wpf

For better separation of concerns and isolation, I have some user controls inside other user controls and I would like all my resources defined only once.
My WPF form and user controls are inside a class library, so no app.xaml file inside my application.

I have the following code in the main form ctor:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(Application.LoadComponent(
     new Uri("/MyProject;component/Themes/theme1.xaml", UriKind.Relative)) as ResourceDictionary);

Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(Application.LoadComponent(
     new Uri("/MyProject;component/Themes/theme2.xaml", UriKind.Relative)) as ResourceDictionary);
```

And no ResourceDictionary define anywhere except in the main window.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="theme1.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="theme2.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

I have turned all my StaticResource into DynamicResource and it seems to work fine but each time I open a user control I have a warning: The resource "resource name" could not be resolved.

What is the good practice here?

Comment: add your resources to Application.Resources.MergedDictionaries in app.xaml instead of code. then designer should recognize them

Comment: As my project is a class library, I think that adding an app.xaml file will not help...